# What's the correct way to code split (lazy-load) an external library into a SvelteKit project

Tags: firebase, vite, sveltekit

### tldr;

I'm getting the following warning when building a SvelteKit project with `@sveltejs/adapter-static`, lazy-loading Firebase JS SDK `9.0.0-beta.2`:

`[vite-plugin-svelte] The following packages did not export their` package.json `file so we could not check the "svelte" field. If you had difficulties importing svelte components from a package, then please contact the author and ask them to export the package.json file. -firebase`

Everything seems to work in real life (i.e. on the client with initially static routes that later make calls to the Firebase API.) **Do I need to stress about this warning?** Note -- I don't think I'm ever "polluting" the static routes with direct Firebase imports, but I may be doing it all wrong. Please see below for my methodology.

### More Info

- firebase: "9.0.0-beta.2"
- @sveltejs/adapter-static: "^1.0.0-next.13",
- @sveltejs/kit: "next",

I'm lazily importing Firebase 9 (beta) into a SvelteKit project. I expose async getters for the various Firebase things like this...

```
import type { FirebaseApp } from 'firebase/app';
import type { Auth } from 'firebase/auth';
// etc...

// basic firebase options plus some emulator config...
import { getEnv } from './env';

let _app: FirebaseApp | null = null;
let _auth: Auth | null = null;
// etc...

export const firebaseApp = async () => {
  if (!_app) {
    const { loadApp } = await import('./load/load-app');
    _app = loadApp(getEnv());
  }
  return _app;

}

export const firebaseAuth = async (): Promise<Auth> => {
  if (!_auth) {
    const app = await firebaseApp();
    const { loadAuth } = await import('./load/load-auth');
    _auth = loadAuth(app, getEnv());
  }
  return _auth;
}
```

The actual firebase imports are in the `load/load-**.ts` files...

```
//load-app.ts
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import type { FirebaseEnvironment } from '../api';

export const loadApp = (env: FirebaseEnvironment): FirebaseApp => {
  const  app = initializeApp(env.options);
  return app;
};
```

```
// load-auth.ts
import type { FirebaseApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, useAuthEmulator, Auth } from 'firebase/auth';
import type { FirebaseEnvironment } from '../api';


export const loadAuth  = (app: FirebaseApp, env: FirebaseEnvironment): Auth => {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  if (
    env.emulators &&
    env.emulators.auth
  ) {
    useAuthEmulator(auth, env.emulators.auth.url, {
      disableWarnings: true
    });
  }
  return auth;
}
```

This works as expected -- i.e. Vite and SvelteKit seem to chunk everything up nicely, and I can do stuff like this in my components....

```
<script>
// SignInForm.svelte
  // the lazy getter from above...
  import { firebaseAuth } from '$lib/firebase';
  import {
    browserLocalPersistence,
    browserSessionPersistence,
    setPersistence,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword
  } from '@firebase/auth';
  const signIn = async () => {
   try {
      const auth = await firebaseAuth();
      const cred = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, ...);
      // etc...
    } catch (error) {
      // handle
    }
  };

</script>
```

Again, all this seems to work, except for the warning on build. I just need somebody more familiar with Vite and SvelteKit to let me know if it's the "right way" (Or not.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning basically says that if the `firebase` package exports any svelte components (which it doesn't), the svelte compiler won't pick it up and won't be able to optimize it. I have seen the warning too and I don't think there is anything to worry about.